# Android EMM custom DPC

Tags: android, mdm, device-policy-manager, emm

I want develop MDM solution which has custom DPC app on android device. As new registration are not allowed for Google play EMM API, How can I create custom DPC ?

AS per documentation there is no way to register new custom DPC